# ruby on rails map attributes to specific columns

Tags: ruby, attributes, dictionary

`@models.map(&:attributes))` returns a list of hashes from each column to its value in the db

How do I limit it so that only specific columns are returns (e.g. just name and id?).

Also, how do I combine multiple columns to a new key => value pair? For example, if a user has first_name and last_name, the above would return

```
[{"first_name" => "foo", "last_name" => "bar"}] but I want it to be [{"name" => "foo bar"}]
```

How do I achieve this transformation? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first part (limiting the attributes in the hash):

```
@models.map {|model| model.attributes.slice(:id, :name)}
```

For combining multiple attribute into a new attribute, the cleanest way is usually an accessor method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then build your hash manually during iteration:

```
@models.map {|model| {:id => model.id, :name => model.name}}
```

If you're using more than one attribute from the attributes hash, you can use merge:

```
@models.map do |model|
  model.attributes.slice(:id, :first_name, :last_name).merge(:name => model.name)
end
```